# Father son relationship

Tags: sources-mekorot, children-parenting

Any body heard of a gemorah where a father has a delicacy which he gives to his son and not to his father ie the grandfather
The grandfather says that how it works  I gave it to my son and not to my father
Any one know where it is ?
Does that mean a person honours his son more than his father?

Answer (score 4):

Here is that Gemara:

> Rav Chuna found a juicy date. He took and wrapped it in his mantle, Rabba his son came and said to (Rav Chuna) “I smelled a juicy date. (Rav Chuna) said to him, My son purity lies within you. (Rav Chuna) gave it (the date) to (Rabba). Meanwhile Abba, (Rabba’s) son, came. So (Rabba) took (the date) and gave it to (Abba). Rav Chuna said to Rabba, “My son you gladdened my heart and now you blunted my teeth. This is why people say a father’s love is for his children, and the love of his child is for his own children. [Sotah 49]